# Naive Bayes questions: continus data, negative data, and MultinomialNB in scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn, naive-bayes

I'm trying something out where I generate points in the plane, and each point is one of two classes. The data most falls in the range $-5 \le x \le 5$ and $-5 \le y \le 5$.

I'm trying to test `MultinomialNB` in scikit-learn against my own implementation of a naive Bayes classifier.

My implementation works as follows: for each data point $(x,y)$, I bin it into a small square $S$. These sqaures/bins are all of equal size and are defined in such a way that they cover my data without overlapping. I'm essentially diving the plane into a grid of squares. Then for each square/bin I count the number of class 1 points that land there, and the number of class 2 points that land there. From my understanding, Multinomial Bayes can now predict as follows: given a new point, find its bin: if there were more class 1 points in that bin, assign class 1, and vice versa.

Is this the most logical way to do this? The most blatant problem is that the smaller the bins/squares, the more bins/squares end up with no data, and can therefore not predict anything.

As for trying this out in scikit-learn, when I pass the data to be `clf.fit()` by `MultinomialNB`, I get `ValueError: Input X must be non-negative`. Why can't negative data be used here? How is scikit-learn handling the continuous data, anyways?

Comment: What you describe does not sound like a naive bayes implementation... just counting classes in a bin is more like a nearest neighbour search or a projection into a smaller space...

Answer (score 4):

#### Why can't negative data be used here?

MultinomialNB assumes that features have [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) which is a generalization of the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). Neither binomial nor multinomial distributions can contain negative values.

#### How is scikit-learn handling the continuous data?

If you want to work with bayesian methods use [GaussianNb](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB) but generally there are a lot of estimators capable of handling continuous data in scikit-learn.

#### Is this the most logical way to do this?

From my perspective it's unwise to work with small piece of data (unless you have strong reason to do so). Statistics tends to work better with large amount of data ([Law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers)).

Moreover data binning is also a dangerous transformation. For example:

[image]

Comment: GaussianNB assumes the continuous data for each category is IID from each covariate, calculates the PDF and (if they did it right) sums up the logPDF values with log priors then it chooses the class with the highest logPosterior or whatever.